# Find an operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 \\-5   \\1\end{matrix} \right)$

**Find an operator $T \in L(U) $ such that $T(u)=u $ and $T$ is self-adjoint.**

I have to show that $T=T^*$ to have a self-adjoint operator T but I know how to start off.

I all I can think is $ T(u) = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 \\-5   \\1\end{matrix} \right)$

Any sort of help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write $T$ as a matrix $A$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the matrix is necessarily Hermitian symmetric.

Comment: Standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ is $ T = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0  \\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)$ then I multiplied this matrix and $u$ i got the vector $u$. How do i continue? I am still stuck. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: I do think the identity operator is what you need in this question. What I mentioned is a more general procedure for, say $Tu = v$ for some given $v$.